# Setar OPTION como Selected com base em valores do Banco

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso criar uma condição para que, se a opção do banco for Smartphone ou Aparelho Comum que apareça no Selected, do contrário, apareça como "Selecionar".

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label>Aparelho</label>
    <select name="aparelho" class="form-control">                                                                                        
        <option selected> <?php echo $row_tel['aparelho'];?> </option>                                                                                       
        <option>Smartphone</option>
        <option>Aparelho Comum</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Atualmente, está ficando desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pois o que está cadastrado o banco atualmente é o "Aparelho Comum" então aparece o valor cadastrado no banco e mais as opções do "Selected".

Comment: Alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

você pode fazer um teste em cada option e exibir selected caso o value seja o mesmo do banco.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
<label>Aparelho</label>
    <select name="aparelho" class="form-control">                                                                                        
        <option <?php if($row_tel['aparelho'] == 'Smartphone') {echo 'selected'; } ?> value="Smartphone">Smartphone</option>
        <option <?php if($row_tel['aparelho'] == 'Aparelho comum') {echo 'selected'; } ?> value="Aparelho comum">Aparelho comum</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Uma dica, de preferência por salvar um id de cada tipo de aparelho no banco de dados:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
<label>Aparelho</label>
    <select name="aparelho" class="form-control">                                                                                        
        <option <?php if($row_tel['aparelho'] == 1) {echo 'selected'; } ?> value="1">Smartphone</option>
        <option <?php if($row_tel['aparelho'] == 2) {echo 'selected'; } ?> value="2">Aparelho comum</option>
    </select>
</div>
```